# C++ cross platform for processes: is POCO lib good? other alternatives?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I would like to use some cross platform C++ library for starting, stopping and getting standard output for processes. I found and I would like to use C++ POCO libraries:
are these good?

What's the best alternatives? I use Boost and they have Boost Process, but is not part of the official release and AFAIK it won't be neither very soon (development stopped at 2008).
Can you advise me a bit on this POCO lib or other?

Comment: @ChristianSeverin Please be aware that every edit you make pushes the question to the front page and can create a lot of noise . If you believe the retagging should happen, ask about it on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any direct experience with the Processes lib in POCO but I'm a big fan of the project in general and the networking and threading libs in particular.  Works great under Windows (MinGW & VS), OS X, and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I have used POCO cross-platform for iOS/Android and it was very straightforward, dynamic pointers, threading and much much more. There was some threshold on getting it running at first, but once first sample was running: no problems... You may want to check out our entire project [here](https://github.com/devdavidkarlsson/Sogeti-MasterThesis-CrossPlatformMobileDevelopment)

Comment: Hi. Indeed! I watch a video about one of the developer (Alex Fabijanic) at BoostCon2012 about type erasure and I like it a lot. He alsoe wrote on ACCU on the same topic. See this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QySTK4cSq7o.